# Extract only content with Scrapy to create WordClouds

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, word-cloud

I am looking for a smart solution to extract only the main information of a range of different webpages. When building wordclouds, I always get the problem of having to define a range of different stopwords (e.g. "links", "contact",...) to only show the actual content. Now I am looking for a way for not creating a list of stopwords each time I scrape a new website.

I had the idea, that certain html tags tend to have more content than others. Is that a good way of filtering in the preprocessing or do you have any other ideas?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could try creating a list of all words you do not want (links, contact, etc..). Then scrape all words on the website and remove the words you do not want. I am honestly not sure your end goal with your `word cloud` but from what information I have, this sounds like the easiest way.

Also if you are unable to think of all words you want to remove. After you scrape all the words, you can look at all the words that repeat a high number of times and see if it a word  you do not want.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/55714934/939364